# .Net C# String.Join how to output "null" instead of empty string if element value is null?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

According to the [MSDN docs for String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) "If any element in value is null, an empty string is used instead."

The code I have pulls data out of a DataTable

```
rotationValues = string.Join<object>(", ",
    from r in rotationData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>() select r[5]);
```

This would result in output similar to this:

```
8, 7, , 12, , , 13,
```

Is there any way to simply have it put "null" in place of an empty string like so:

```
8, 7, null, 12, null, null, 13, null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select

```
r[5] ?? "null"
```

instead of just `r[5]`.

Also, just remove the `<object>` part when you call the generic method. It will still be an `IEnumerable<object>` that you join, but the compiler will infer the type parameter automatically.

**ADDITION after comment:**

Your `r[5]` might be [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx). Then, this is not a "real" null reference, but its `ToString` implementation returns `""`. So in that case, the `string.Join` documentation wasn't strictly relevant. Therefore, try to select something like

```
(r[5] == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(r[5])) ? "null" : r[5]
```

or maybe

```
(r[5] == null || r[5] is DBNull) ? "null" : r[5]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I spoke too soon, the answer looked good but once implemented it didn't actually replace the NULL values.  Here is how rotationData comes about  DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();  mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);  DataTable rotationData = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];

Comment: Thanks again Jeppe, I also posted a follow-up question which resulted in folks pointing out that null does not equal DBNull, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621962/net-c-sharp-operator-didnt-trigger-for-system-dbnull-type-in-datatable-data

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jeppe's answer, I am not sure why his way didn't actually work for me, I confirmed that the null values in `r[5]` are actually of type `System.DBNull` yet it didn't do the replacement with "null".

Here is what I ended up doing instead:

```
rotationValues = string.Join(", ",
    from r in rotationData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    select (r[5].ToString().Length == 0 ? "null" : r[5]));
```

Which is a conditional that I didn't want to do, but I had a look at this page [C# Empty Strings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/empty-string) where the guy benchmarked different ways to check whether a string is empty and the length method was the fastest.  So I figured to check for the length and join "null" if the length is 0 and the actual `r[5]` value when it is not zero.

It would still be good to figure out why ?? "null" didn't work though.

**EDIT FOR REFERENCE:**
The issue is indeed that ?? operates on `null` and not `DBNull`.  See also [.Net C# ?? operator didn't trigger for System.DBNull type in DataTable DataRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621962/net-c-sharp-operator-didnt-trigger-for-system-dbnull-type-in-datatable-data)