# ?? operator didn't trigger System.DBNull type in DataTable DataRow

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, null

This is a follow-up question to [.Net C# String.Join how to output “null” instead of empty string if element value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621347/net-c-sharp-string-join-how-to-output-null-instead-of-empty-string-if-element) where the answer suggested to use the `??` operator to define a custom null value, but the replacement never got triggered.

```
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
DataTable rotationData = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];

rotationValues = string.Join(", ",
    from r in rotationData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    select r[5] ?? "null");
```

When I change the code to:

```
rotationValues = string.Join(", ",
    from r in rotationData.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    select r[5].GetType());
```

I can observe that the data type for elements that have valid data in them is `System.Double` whereas the data type for elements which are NULL is `System.DBNull`.  Does `??` not operate on `System.DBNull`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No `DBNull` and `null` is not the same thing.
But you can write this instead:

```
select r[5] == DBNull.Value ? "null" : r[5]);
```

Another possibility is to use `Field` extension method, it will give you strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the specified row, and the `??` operator will work.

```
select r.Field<string>(5) ?? "null";
```

Answer (score 3):

`??` operates on the programming language `null`, not on the database `DBNull`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/934efkk6.aspx):

> Do not confuse the notion of null in an object-oriented programming language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column.